# How to map Database with Models in Drift / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, drift

I´m using a **local DB (SQLite with Drift)** to persist state. A **Repository** reads and writes Data to the database and **should provide an according Model** via it´s API.

So the **Database returns a DataClass object** and I need to **map this data to my ModelClass**. Doing that mapping manually in the Repository in each method is anoying and error prone and adding some kind of "fromDataClass" and "toDataClass" to the model itself feels wrong cause the model should be abstracted from the concrete database implementation (and so doesn´t need to know anything about where it´s stored).

However Drift offers support for **TypeConverters** (https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/type_converters/) and I´m not sure if this is the way to go? **What is the best way to deal with data mapping when the data comes from a local database?**